# Help with a BST insert function

Tags: c++, g++, helper

Hey so I am attempting to write a BST but I am having a lot of errors and I am pretty overwhelmed and lost on what to do.  Can you guys take a look and point out anything that is off. The teacher wasn't very useful at all at explaining anything.

header in the .h file

```
class Tree
{
public:
    bool insert(int k, string s);

private:
    struct Node
    {
        int key;
        string data;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
    };
    Node* root;
    bool insert(Node *& root, int k, string s);
};
```

the .cpp file

```
bool Tree::insert(int k, string s)
{
    return insert(root, k, s);
}
bool Tree::insert (Node *& root, int k, string s)
{
    if (root == NULL){
        root = new Node;
        root->key = k;
        root->data = s;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (root == k)
        return false;
    else if (root->key < k)
        insert (root ->left, k);
    else
        insert (root -> right, k);
}
```

Comment: Aaaaand the errors are? Please post them here, it's gonna be easier for each of us (:

Comment: Also, you need to start compiling/testing your code, while you're writing it. The errors can  be found easier - just writing hundreds of lines without testing and compiling is a bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have a lot of untested code. You will have to get the features working one at a time.

Furthermore, I see at least one instance of duplicated effort already. The `preOrder` and `postOrder` methods should be slight variations of the same algorithm, yet one is loop-based and the other works by function recursion.

Set these source files aside, create a new project, and copy-paste over *one* feature at a time. Test thoroughly before moving on to the next feature. If you reach a feature that might already be latent in the existing code, don't copy-paste from the old code, but instead leverage the existing tested code.

## Edit

That looks like it should work. Here are a couple stylistic criticisms, if you want them :v) .

1. The `Node` structure should have its own constructor. Always provide a constructor to help guarantee that nothing can be in an invalid state.
2. Likewise, something needs to set `root` to `NULL` when you create a new `Tree`.
3. Changing the value of the `root` argument is not good style. At first glance, it looks like `left` and `right` never receive non-`NULL` values. Personally I favor a pointer-to-pointer here, but some might agree with your implementation instead.

Comment: actually, can u take a look at my tree::insert code(the helper and the function) ?? I a little confused on how to use the &*

Comment: @king: I'm not suggesting starting over, this is a technique to keep tested code separated from untested code. I'll update my answer to reflect your updated question, but it might have been better to start a new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you have a missing bracket at the end of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Not looking at actual implementation, there are lots of interface-related pitfalls. Here are some of them:

- You are missing [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in header file.
- Saying "using namespace std" in global scope of the header file that gets included is allowed, but it very bad style.
- `Tree::findKey` method accepts string as non-constant reference, why?
- `Tree::insert` accepts string by value, which involves unnecessary copying, what for?
- `preOrder` and `levelOrder` expects pointer to a function. What if I want to invoke a class method, or pass additional arguments? I'd say you better off with predicate there, or `boost::function`.
- Methods that do not modify state (data inside a class) are not market as constant (`const` modifier). For example, `isEmpty ()` method.
- `makeCopy` method is not [exception-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Exception_safety).
- Signed integer is used instead of `size_t`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your first BST can be hard ... Taking the advice of Potatoswatter, I would first start with making sure you have a *VERY SOLID* insert function working before going anywhere else.  So you can create the class for your BST, including the declarations for the functions, but in their definitions, just make them empty functions, for example:

In your header file:

```
class BST
{
    public:
        BST();
        bool insert(int k, const string& s);
        bool findKey(int k, string& s);
        int maxKey();

        /* ... the rest of your class ...*/
};
```

In your .cpp file:

```
#include "BST.h"

BST::BST()
{
    /*initialize anything required for your insert function to work*/
}

//pass in a const reference for your string argument, 
//or else you could end up doing a lot
//of extra processing creating a new copy of your string on the stack for
//each insertion call
bool BST::insert(int k, const string& s)
{
    /* write your insertion algorithm implementation */
}

//make the rest of your function definitions that don't
//apply to insertion empty so you can compile and test your insertion algorithm
//without adding more cruft
bool BST::findKey(int k, string& s) {}

int BST::maxKey() {}

/* continue process for the rest of the class */
```

Now with this approach, you can test to make sure you are properly inserting nodes into your tree without crashing, etc., and once that is done, you can test to see if you can find the nodes you've inserted.  After that, you can complete the definitions for the rest of the functions that take care of deletion, iteration, etc.  But by leaving the definitions empty for functions you don't need for each stage, you can properly build-up your solution without having a mess of compiler errors and other non-related items keeping you back from building the actual interface for the task-at-hand.  In other words you can't find or delete a node from a tree that hasn't has a node properly inserted in it in the first place without issues, so you don't want to go around chasing your tail on those steps when you're not getting the first step right.  Also you may find when you implement a later step, like finding a node, that there are still insertion problems ... if you've only implemented the full definitions for insertion and finding a node, then those are the only two functions you're going to have to worry about fixing.

So break it down into its basic parts (inserting, finding, deleting, and then everything else), and you'll get the job done :-)

Comment: Just be glad he's not starting you off with a Red-Black tree :-)